# Bulk data insert from text file gives a OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error

Tags: sql, insert, oledb, bulk

I am new to SQL and am trying to import a text file (based on the current date) from directory "C:\Import". The filenames are generated based on the date by another application, and is named something like 20161109.txt.

The query below is a part of the solution I want to make it work.     In this I am trying to read the latest or current .txt file  from the given     directory and get it in a temp.     From there i want to convert and insert it into a table. While doing this I get the error below. Please need some advice on this.  Actually if this works, the other part on which I will be working on is to   update the data in the database from same file (after checking the date and the ISCREATED field in the FILES table). Can anyone help me out with this?

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTextDate]

AS

DECLARE @ToDate VARCHAR(20)   
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(100)  
DECLARE @FULLPATH VARCHAR(300)  
DECLARE @FormatTextName VARCHAR(500)  
DECLARE @DateFromFileName VARCHAR(500)  
DECLARE @FormatPathFile VARCHAR(500)  
DECLARE @Runner VARCHAR(2500)  
DECLARE @ROOT VARCHAR(100)='C:\Import\'

SET @ToDate= Convert(VARCHAR,GetDate(),112)

INSERT INTO TEMPFILE (FILENAME,DEPTH,ISFILE)   
EXEC xp_DirTree @ROOT,1,1 

SET @FileName= (SELECT FILENAME FROM TEMPFILE where RIGHT(LEFT(FILENAME, CHARINDEX('.', FILENAME) - 1), 8) = @ToDate) 

SET @FULLPATH= Concat(@ROOT,@FileName)   
SET @FormatPathFile = RIGHT(@FULLPATH,12)   
SET @FormatTextName = @FULLPATH           
SET @DateFromFileName= RIGHT(LEFT(@FormatTextName, CHARINDEX('.', @FormatTextName) - 1), 8) 

BEGIN 
SET @Runner = "BULK INSERT TEMPLOGSCANDATA FROM '"+@FULLPATH+"' WITH (FIRSTROW = 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ') "
END

EXEC (@Runner) 
INSERT LOGSCANDATA (SCANDATE,SCANINTIME,DATA1,DATA2,CARDNUMMER,DATA3)

SELECT Convert(Date,SCANDATE,108),LEFT(SCANINTIME,2) + ':' + RIGHT(SCANINTIME,2),DATA1,DATA2,LEFT(CARDNUMMER,5) + ':' + RIGHT(CARDNUMMER,5),DATA3
FROM TEMPLOGSCANDATA

INSERT FILES (FILENAME, CREATIONDATE,ISCREATED) 
SELECT @FormatPathFile,COnvert(Date,@DateFromFileName,108),0

TRUNCATE TABLE TEMPLOGSCANDATA
TRUNCATE TABLE TEMPFILE
```

---

```
  As sample 20161109.txt file with its records(which can grow for that
  specific date):
  161109 1243 1 1 0011847470 00
  161109 1242 1 1 0006520226 00
  161109 1243 1 1 0006460937 00
  161109 1242 1 1 0006461484 00
  161109 1242 1 1 0006457881 00
  161109 1243 1 1 0006553565 00
  161109 1243 1 1 0006562191 00
```

---

```
(7 row(s) affected) 
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file. 
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error. 
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 9 
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Comment: As you can see in the message you get `7 rows` affected....it means that some data get inserted....and the error is pretty clear....in some line of the file an unexpected line ending is find it on the file, so the execution halts...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Hackerman, the error message given there is not based on the given sample .txt, sorry my bad. it actually fire the EXEC xp_DirTree very well, the only place it stumb as i see it is when the bulk data is inserted.

Comment: And the error message for the given sample txt?..you can edit your question to include that ;)

Comment: Just updated it to the actually file '20161109.txt'

Comment: Try adding this option `ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'`

Comment: I just tried that but unfortunately the same result. Actually what i see is that the affected 7 rows are not the records of the file '20161109.txt', but the total of the file in C:\Import. Today i get 8 rows affected.